# PyQt5 Resize app for different displays

Tags: python, resize, pyqt5, qapplication

I am using PyQt5 and Python 3.6.4 to design a ui for a program. It was made on a 720p monitor however now using the same code on a 4k monitor, everything is tiny apart from the text. How would I go about resizing the whole app to look the same on all monitors: (720p, 1080p, 4k, etc.)
The program is to be run on windows through an executable created through compiling the python code.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat system dependent, so it would help if you mentioned your target platform(s).

Because PyQt5 is just a wrapper around Qt5, I think [High DPI Displays](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) from the Qt manual applies. Citing the relevant bit (but you should read the whole thing):

> In order to get an application designed for low DPI values running on a high resolution monitors quickly, consider one of the scaling options (let the application run as DPI Unaware on Windows or set the environment variable QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR to "1". These options may incur some scaling or painting artifacts, though.
>
> In the longer term, the application should be adapted to run unmodified:
>
> - Always use the qreal versions of the QPainter drawing API.
> - Size windows and dialogs in relation to the screen size.
> - Replace hard-coded sizes in layouts and drawing code by values calculated from font metrics or screen size.

In a shell, you would do something like:

```
$ export QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=1
$ python my_application.py
```

Comment: Please see edits. Also please note that the program is to be run by people with no programming knowledge and therefore I would require the program to set up the resizing on its own.

Comment: This is why I advised you to read the entire article :) It's too much to cite here. The environment var is just to test whether it works.

Comment: Ok will do. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ended up getting it to work by setting the QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO to auto. This is said to be deprecated but im not sure why. It seems to work well.

Comment: I think you're supposed to set `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling` instead. In C++, it would be `myApplication.setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);`, not sure how exactly that translates to Python.

Comment: Your solution worked but oddly only through setting the variable through the script. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Simple 1 line fix for any who need

`os.environ["QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR"] = "1"`

Answer (score 1):

Many PyQt6 / PyQt5 show small screen using : PyQt6-WebEngine

```
    # Set the QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR environment variable
    
    import os
    os.environ['QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR'] = '1'

    #....before
    #....
    if __name__ == "__main__":
```

this will solve issue to display small screen for high end laptop or 4K screen